# Graphen Django: Batch requests should receive a list, but received {'query': XXX}

Tags: python, graphql, graphene-python, graphene-django

I have enabled the batch query processing functionality in [**Graphene-Django**](https://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/) by adding **`batch=True`** to the **`.as_view(...)`** method as,

```
urlpatterns = [
    # other URL patterns,
    path('graphql/', CustomGraphQLView.as_view(schema=schema, batch=True), name='graphql')
]
```

After that, I sent the request (see below screenshot) with a query to the server using [***Postman***](https://www.postman.com/) client, but got an error

**GraphQL Query**

```
{
  musicians {
    id
    name
  }
}
```

**Error Response**

> {
> "errors": [
> {
> "message": "Batch requests should receive a list, but received {'query': 'bla bla'}"
> }
> ] }

**Postman Screenshot**

[image: request screenshot]

#### Question

1. What is the proper way to send the *GraphQL batch requests* to ***Graphene-Django***?
2. How can I send *GraphQL batch requests* to *Graphene-Django* using ***Postman*** client?

Answer (score 0):

The *Graphene-Django* expects the queries as a ***list of dicts*** (or JSON Array of JSON Objects).

So you need to build a payload as,

```json
[
    {
        "query": "{musicians{id}}"
    },
    {
        "query": "{musicians{name}}"
    },
    {
        "query": "{musicians{id,name,}}"
    }
]
```

Make sure that, the request should be sent as ***raw JSON*** from the POSTMAN client (or any *non-GraphQL* client)

**Result Screenshot**

[image]